# Comparing 2 questions about Riesz representation theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I am trying to answer this question (#8 on page.404 in Royden and Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis") it is for general measure space and for Riesz representation theorem for the dual of $L^q$:

Give an example of a measure space $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ for which the Riesz Representation Theorem does extend to the case $p=\infty.$

But, I have found this question here:

[riesz representation theorem for the case when p is infinity for the case of lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736431/riesz-representation-theorem-for-the-case-when-p-is-infinity-for-the-case-of-leb)

Does this means that my question is wrong? If not, is there any hint for solving it?

Answer (score 2):

Read the exercise, and the linked question, more carefully.

The linked question shows that the statement is not true *in general*; that there exist measure spaces for which it fails.  That does not mean that it fails for *every* measure space; there could still be other measure spaces $(X,\mu)$ for which the dual of $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is indeed $L^1(X,\mu)$.  All we know from the linked question is that $X=\mathbb{N}$ (with $\mu$ being counting measure) won't work.

There is nothing wrong with the question in Royden. Such spaces do exist, and in fact some extremely simple examples will work...

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: No, I think it would be better for you to find it yourself.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518072/let-mu-be-the-measure-constructed-in-the-riesz-representation-theorem-is-m will this help me in constructing my example?

Comment: @Secretly: You are thinking much too hard.  Let me emphasize the phrase **extremely simple** in my last sentence.

Comment: what about this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581474/is-l-inftyx-mu-dual-of-l1x-mu-if-x-is-discrete ?

Comment: I am really unable to construct an example ..... give me hints

Comment: What is the very simplest measure space you can think of?

Comment: the space with counting measure

Comment: "The space"?  Which one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104244/discussion-between-nate-eldredge-and-secretly).